# Django - Pegando informações de formulario

Tags: python, django

Tenho um template chamado `listaarquivos.html` onde aparece uma tabela com informações de um objeto do `models.py` chamado `JOB`.

No entanto, agora preciso filtrar essa tabela que por data. Inseri então dois inputs no `listaarquivos.html`, `datainicial` e `datafinal`, e um botão pesquisar.

Como que eu pego essas informações das datas inseridas pelo usuário no momento que ele clica no botão pesquisar, para filtrar esses valores no banco de dados e retornar na tela?

Esta é minha view:

```
def listaarquivos(request):
    ajob = Job.objects.order_by('nome_usuario').filter(status_job = 'OK -  Impresso')
    return render_to_response('listaarquivos.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'ajob':ajob}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve colocar o seu formulário para fazer GET na própria página:

```
...
<form method="GET">
...
```

Na sua view, você deve verificar se tem algum parametro de data_inicial e final para fazer a consulta.

```
from datetime import datetime
data_inicial = request.GET.get('data_inicial')
data_final = request.GET.get('data_final')
# supondo que a data esteja no formato "%Y-%m-%d
dI = datetime.strptime(data_inicial, "%Y-%m-%d")
dF = datetime.strptime(data_final, "%Y-%m-%d")

objs = Job.objects.filter(data_initial__gte=dI,data_final__lte=dF)
```